# Como Fazer redirect após autenticação no STS?

Tags: c#, webforms, autenticação

Minha aplicação autentica usuários por meio de STS. A autenticação consegue ir até o STS e validar o PIN do usuário no cartão. Mas como faço para ele redirecionar para a página "home" do meu site após a autenticação?

Adendo:

1. Não tenho acesso ao admin do STS;
2. Utilizo o componente `FederatedPassiveSignIn` contido em: `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls`;
3. Tentei Utilizar o Método `Signed_in` para tentar capturar o momento após a autenticação para o STS mas não funcionou;
4. A maneira que conseguia fazer o redirect anteriormente era usando o Evento `Load`, porém, este é executado toda vez que a pagina é carregada (óbvio).

Segue Código:

```asp
<div style="margin-left: 360px; margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px;">
        <wif:FederatedPassiveSignIn ID="FederatedPassiveSignIn1" runat="server"
            Issuer="<%$AppSettings:CORP.STS.Certificado%>"
            RequireHttps="False" Realm="<%$AppSettings:CORP.STS.UrlCliente%>"
            UseFederationPropertiesFromConfiguration="false" RememberMeText="Lembre minha Senha."
            SignInImageUrl="~/Images/ec_b.gif" TitleText="Autenticar Certificado Digital" OnSignedIn="FederatedPassiveSignIn1_SignedIn" >
            <SignInButtonStyle Height="80px" />
        </wif:FederatedPassiveSignIn>
        <div id="errorMessage">
            <asp:Label Text="text" ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" style="margin-left:-200px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

e da parte do *code behind*:

```asp
 protected void FederatedPassiveSignIn1_SignedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("MinhaPagina.aspx");
 }
```

Comment: Não é possível realizar uma rotina Ajax que retorne se o usuário está logado?

Comment: não. somente saberei se o usuario está logado se o STS me informar que sim ou que não.

Comment: Então... Não é possível fazer uma consulta periódica ao método que retorna o status de login, e tomar a ação pertinente a partir desse momento? Você teria um server side que apenas retornaria o status, e ficaria a cargo do JavaScript, via AJAX, checar o status de login do usuário e redirecioná-lo, se for o caso.

Comment: Funciona assim, A autenticação Passiva, vai até o STS, faz o que tem que fazer por la. e me retorna um Token dizendo se esta autenticado ou não. O ponto é: Onde verifico o token? em que evento? a partir desse ponto saberei como redirecionar para página. Não tem como ver isso via JS, pois tenho que ver a Cadeia de Claims que o STS me retornou.

Comment: É cara, infelizmente nesse caso não vou poder te ajudar... Não entendo da arquitetura que você está utilizando. Vamos torcer para que apareça alguém mais esclarecido por aqui!

Comment: @okevinlira Você pode colocar o código completo da sua classe `FederatedPassiveSignIn`? Desconfio que o evento não está sendo disparado.

Comment: Cigano, FederatedPassiveSignIn é um classe de Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls; não tem como eu te dar o codigo dela rs,

Comment: @Kenny Rafael, é um pergunta de C# Sim! apesar de não ter trecho de código (grande) C# no corpo da pergunta, como que eu resolveria uma autenticação por Windows Federation Authentication (WIF) se não fosse por C#?

Comment: não foi eu que removi a tag de c#...

Comment: Vish, foi mal então, é que apareceu teu nome na revisão, enfim, seja la quem for, fez errado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui contornar assim... não é a melhor forma, (acredito) mas funciona.

```
protected void FederatedPassiveSignIn1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) return;

            try
            {

                var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;
                if (principal == null || !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return;

                var identity = (IClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
                string userId = "";
                var cpf = "";
                foreach (var c in identity.Claims.Where(c => c.ClaimType.ToLower().Contains("login")))
                    userId = c.Value;

                var usuario = ObterUsuario(principal);
                var juris = new ServicoJurisdicao.JurisdicaoClient();
                var jurisdicoesDeUsuario = juris.ConsultarJurisdicoesUsuario(usuario);

                foreach (var jurisdicao in jurisdicoesDeUsuario)
                {
                    identity.Claims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.CORP.com.br/identity/claims/Jurisdicao", jurisdicao.ToString(),
                        ClaimValueTypes.String, ObterNomeEmissor()));
                }

                //Cada claim possui também um tipo, uma string que define o tipo de informação contida:
                Response.Write("Tipo de Claim: " + identity.Claims[0].ClaimType);


                var lookupIpAddres = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
                var ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;

                var sessionProxy = SessionProxy.getInstance();
                sessionProxy.setConfUserIP(ipAddress);
                sessionProxy.setConfUserId(userId);
                sessionProxy.setIdentity(identity);

                /*Forms authentication*/
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, true);
                /*Forms authentication*/
                Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/"));
            }

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblError.Text = err.Message;
                PECv2.Handlers.SimpleLog.SaveLogEventvwrError(err, "PecV2 - Login");
                lblError.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
        }
```